# Why is my Webview resizing itself?

Tags: android, layout, plugins, webview, settings

I'm a noob to android development and my webview resizes itself whenever i try to play video.  In order to make the webview play video i had to add the line of code:

```
youtube.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
```

In my layout, I have my webview above a listview. However, now when the webview plays video it becomes fullscreen and covers listview.  this was not happening before i added the line above.  How do I stop my webview from resizing itself?  Any help is greatly appreciated?

Here is my layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/LLvideos" >


<WebView
        android:id="@+id/webViewyoutube"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="350dp" >
    </WebView>

<!-- List view -->
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/videolist"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:divider="#00000000"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp" >
</ListView>
```

Here is my video link

```
youtube.loadUrl("http://link.brightcove.com/services/player/bcpid1683318714001?bckey=AQ~~,AAAAC59qSJk~,vyxcsD3OtBPHZ2UIrFX2-wdCLTYNyMNn&bclid=1644543007001&bctid=1858951133001");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are have a scaling issue.  Try youtube.setInitialScale(50).  This should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the webview layout like this:

```
webview.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
```

Comment: Thanks for responding, but that didn't work.  it also says that LayoutAlgorithm is deprecated.